# CodedUI, SpecFlow: Trying to get the menu options from a button

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, specflow

There is a button with a dropdown and 2 options/menuitems in my application. I am able to click the button using codedUI but I am unable to click the menuitems from the button. Following the C# code that I wrote for the purpose.

[image]

```
    WinButton _messageMenuItem = new WinButton(ToolBar);
   _messageMenuItem.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Messages (4)");
   _messageMenuItem.WindowTitles.Any(s => regex.IsMatch(s));
   Click(_messageMenuItem);//**Works**
   WinWindow _messagesdropdown = new WinWindow(MessageMenuItem);
   _messagesdropdown.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Messages (4)DropDown"); //DropDown
   _messagesdropdown.WindowTitles.Any(s => regex.IsMatch(s));
   Click(_messagesdropdown);//**Doesnt work**
   UITestControlCollection AllMenuItems = _messageMenuItem.GetChildren();
   UITestControlCollection AllFirstMenuItems = _messagesdropdown.GetChildren();
   //Click(AllMenuItems[0]);//**Doesnt work**
   //Click(AllFirstMenuItems[0]);//**Doesnt work**
   WinMenuItem _textMessagesMenuItem = new WinMenuItem();
   _textMessagesMenuItem.SearchProperties.Add(WinMenuItem.PropertyNames.Name, "Text Messages (4)"); //Text
   _textMessagesMenuItem.WindowTitles.Any(s => regex.IsMatch(s));
   return _textMessagesMenuItem;
```

Comment: It has been a while since I used CodedUI tests. I think the "name" property is incorrect. You need to search for the text in the menu item. Does `WinButton.PropertyNames.Text` exist? Your search criteria should be looking at the visible text, not the name of the control.

Comment: Currently I have found a way to re-use the coded UI recording. I will have to check the WinButton.PropertyNames.Text later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by recording the control in Coded UI & using the generated class for the WinMenu Item. So the code upto clicking the button remains the same.

```
WinButton _messageMenuItem = new WinButton(ToolBar);
_messageMenuItem.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Messages (4)");
_messageMenuItem.WindowTitles.Any(s => regex.IsMatch(s));
Click(_messageMenuItem);//**Works**
```

But after this, recording from UI test is used to get the menu item

```
public class UIItemWindow : WinWindow
        {
            //Use this button for UI Messages window
            public UIItemWindow()
            {
                #region Search Criteria
                this.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.AccessibleName,"Messages (4)DropDown");
                this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
                #endregion
            }

            #region Properties
            public WinMenuItem UITextMessages4MenuItem
            {
                get
                {
                    if ((this.mUITextMessages4MenuItem == null))
                    {
                        this.mUITextMessages4MenuItem = new WinMenuItem(this);
                        #region Search Criteria
                        this.mUITextMessages4MenuItem.SearchProperties.Add(WinMenuItem.PropertyNames.Name,"Text Messages (4)");
                        #endregion
                    }
                    return this.mUITextMessages4MenuItem;
                }
            }
```

Click action is performed as follows

```
UIItemWindow testWindow = new UIItemWindow();
WinMenuItem _textMessagesMenuItem = testWindow.UITextMessages4MenuItem;
Mouse.click(_textMessagesMenuItem );//**Works**
```